# Where can I get jsde_sdk.jar for ArcSDE 10?

Tags: jar, metadata, gis, geospatial

I had an environment working with no problems, with `Geonetwork` `harvesting` metadata from `ArcSDE` *9.3*. It was done trhu the following libraries, copied from the ArcSDE installation to the Geonerwork `lib` dir:

- `jsde_sdk.jar`
- `jpe_sdk.jar`
- `concurrent.jar`
- `icu4_3_2.jar`

After upgrading to `ArcSDE`*10*, the harvesting stopped working.

It is certainly because I'm using `*.jar`s for version *9.3*, while having a *v10* `ArcSDE`, but the new installation doesn't have those `jar`s.

Does anyone knows where to get them?

Comment: did you get them? I guess they are provided when buying ArcGIS Server 10?

Comment: No, I couldn't get it. I guess they came with ArcGIS 10, but after the updrade (someone else did it) we couldn't find the disks, and ESRI asked for €€ to send them again.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but it still comes up quite a bit.  If you have current maintenance with Esri you can request the physical media from your account manager. They are no longer available for download on either the Customer Care Portal or MyEsri.